# 1st gen iPad Mini screen replacement

Tags: ipad

I have the above iPad Mini. I need to take it to Apple for an out of warranty screen replacement. If they give me a replacement what will I get as Apple no longer makes the 32GB 1st generation iPad Mini.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not sell the 1st Generation iPad Mini any more, but they generally have stock for this purpose.

You may get a refurbished iPad that matches the specs and color of your iPad Mini or you may get the screen replaced on your iPad.